# What does this command do "yes | mkfs -T ext2 $(mount | grep "/ " | cut -d" " -f1)"

Tags: linux, command-line

Hi please explain to me this command I found about formatting drives in linux:

yes | mkfs -T ext2 $(mount | grep "/ " | cut -d" " -f1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets all file systems and their mountpoints (`mount`), selects the line with the partition mounted at `/` (root, `grep "/ "`), and interprets it as space delimited data, selecting the first column (i.e. the device, `cut -d" " -f1`).

Then it converts this partition to ext2 file system (`mkfs -T ext2`, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mkfs)) and confirms all questions that might come up (`yes`).

---

In short, it makes the partition that is mounted as `/` into ext2.